# XGBoost - feature importance just depends on the location of the feature in the data

Tags: python, feature-selection, xgboost

I'm trying to do some feature selection using XGBoost, but the feature importance chart just spits out the features in order of appearance. The feature that is in the first column in the xtrain data is by far most important and then second is second, etc.

It seems like a sign that the model is not working properly as its not really learning anything... any advice on what could be going wrong?

UPDATE:
Correlation Matrix
https://ibb.co/3shDJjD

Model Code:

```
params = {
  'subsample':0.5,
  'learning_rate': 0.3,
  'max_depth':8,
  'num_parallel_trees' : 20,
  'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
  'verbosity':0,
  }
watchlist = [(train, 'train'), (test, 'val')]
reg = xgb.train(params, train, num_boost_round=5, early_stopping_rounds=5, evals=watchlist)
```

Results:

```
[0] train-rmse:0.274535 val-rmse:0.27431
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'val-rmse' will be used for early stopping.

Will train until val-rmse hasn't improved in 5 rounds.
[1] train-rmse:0.273472 val-rmse:0.273653
[2] train-rmse:0.272796 val-rmse:0.27341
[3] train-rmse:0.272318 val-rmse:0.27334
[4] train-rmse:0.271943 val-rmse:0.273346
[5] train-rmse:0.271604 val-rmse:0.273374
[6] train-rmse:0.271218 val-rmse:0.273442
[7] train-rmse:0.270927 val-rmse:0.273529
[8] train-rmse:0.270641 val-rmse:0.273561
Stopping. Best iteration:
[3] train-rmse:0.272318 val-rmse:0.27334
```

Feature importance (note that 0 and 1 are first). If I change the order of the columns in the xtrain, the feature importance will also change and first two columns will always be two most important features.
https://ibb.co/QcHwbNg

Comment: A MWE (code and data, if possible) would be really helpful here. How's the model performing? Are the features correlated, with each other or the target? What hyperparameters are you using?

Comment: Adding big update including correlation matrix for features, model code, results, and feature importance.

Comment: Very interesting.  I could see the importances being unstable for a less-than-great model, but why the first features always get inflated beats me.  Maybe try a different measure of feature importance (shap, permutation), and/or column subsampling?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this chunk of code to plot the feature importance of your data. It is also possible that your data is columned with decreasing importance.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load data
X = 
y = 
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
plot_importance(model)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: ya I've been using that. The result is that the feature importance is perfectly correlated with the position of that column in xtrain. If I rearrange the columns in xtrain and rerun the model, the feature importance chart perfectly matches the new order of the columns. So XGBoost is just using the first feature in my xtrain and nothing else really.

Comment: Is your input features linearly independent? If not,then it is possible that correleted features importance will be calculated the way they were encountered. Make sure your input columns are linearly independent.

Comment: all features are independent of each other

Comment: You should see correlation matrix of your dataset to confirm that the correlation of your columns are less than 0.8 or around for each of them.If it is then you might have some error in your code or dataset.

Comment: no correlations > 50%